# How to place a texture correctly over a custom shape?

Tags: three.js, threejs-editor

I'm a newbie in ThreeJs, but I wanted to create a ribbon-shaped geometry and place a text texture on it. So far, everything works: I have an extruded trefoil knot shape, and I want to place a text texture that moves along the shape's surface. I can see the texture but can't make the desired effect.

This is what I got:

[image]

This is what I want (the smiley faces going through the shape):

[image]

This is my code:

```
const Ribbon = () => {
    const meshRef = useRef();
  
    const numPoints = 500; // Number of points to define the ribbon
    const curveAmount = 0.01; // Amount of curve for the points
    const ribbonWidth = 0.5; // Width of the ribbon
    const textureSpeed = 2; // Speed factor for texture movement
    const textureAmplitude = 0.1; // Amplitude of the texture movement

    const path = [];
    for (let t = 0; t < numPoints; t++) {
      const k = (t / numPoints) * 2 * Math.PI;
      const x = Math.sin(3 * k) * 2;
      const y = Math.sin(2 * k) * 2;
      const z = Math.cos(3 * k) * 2;
      path.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
    }
  

    path.push(path[0]);
  

    const ribbonShape = new THREE.Shape([
      new THREE.Vector2(-ribbonWidth / 2, 0),
      new THREE.Vector2(ribbonWidth / 2, 0),
      new THREE.Vector2(ribbonWidth / 2, curveAmount),
      new THREE.Vector2(-ribbonWidth / 2, curveAmount),
    ]);
  
    const ribbonGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(ribbonShape, {
      steps: numPoints,
      extrudePath: new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(path),
      bevelEnabled: false,
    });
  
 
    const vertices = ribbonGeometry.getAttribute("position");
    const uvs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < vertices.count; i++) {
      const vertex = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(vertices, i);
      const u = (vertex.x + ribbonWidth / 2) / ribbonWidth; // Normalize x position to range [0, 1]
      const v = (vertex.y / curveAmount + Math.sin(vertex.y * textureSpeed) * textureAmplitude) % 1; 
      uvs.push(u, v);
    }
    ribbonGeometry.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
  

    const ribbonMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        u_time: { value: 0 },
        u_texture: { value: smileyLinePink },
      },
      vertexShader: `
        uniform float u_time;
        varying vec2 vUv;
  
        void main() {
          vUv = uv;
          vec3 transformed = vec3(position);
          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(transformed, 1.0);
        }
      `,
      fragmentShader: `
      varying vec2 vUv;
      uniform float u_time;
      uniform sampler2D u_texture;
      
      void main() {
        float time = u_time;
      
        vec2 uv = vUv;
        uv = fract(uv + vec2(time, 0.0));
        
        vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
        
        gl_FragColor = color;
      }
      `,
    });
  
    useFrame((state, delta) => {
      if (meshRef.current) {
  
        // meshRef.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
        meshRef.current.material.u_time += delta  
      }
    });
  
    return (
      <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]} geometry={ribbonGeometry} material={ribbonMaterial} ref={meshRef}>
      </mesh>
    );
  };

 return (

    <>
      <OrbitControls enableDamping />
      <color attach="background" args={["#000000"]} />
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      <Ribbon />
 </>
  );
};
```

Various shaders as well